Preserve Toml comments
I'm looking to read the Toml configuration, modify a specific value, and save it again. However, the document contains comments, which disappear upon saving.
Any suggestions on how to work around this behavior?
Java Code example:
package org.example;

import com.moandjiezana.toml.Toml;
import com.moandjiezana.toml.TomlWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Toml4jExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Toml toml = new Toml().read(new File("config.toml"));
        Map<String, Object> configValues = toml.toMap();
        configValues.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));

        configValues.put("test_key", "0.8");

        TomlWriter writer = new TomlWriter();
        writer.write(configValues, new File("config.toml"));
    }
}

Configuration Toml Example:
# test_behaviour
# test 2
test_key = "0.8"
app_name = "MyApplication"
exampleKey = "newValue"
app_version = "1.0.0"

#test123
[server]
port = 8080
host = "localhost"


The source doesn't look like it preserves the comments, so it can't write them either. I'd file a bug report / feature request with the author. Or look for another TOML library; the one you're using has some code that I'd have not let through in a code review.

I’m voting to close this question because there's nothing we can do here; the used library doesn't support this.

@Robert the current library im using is toml4j, im more than OK to change to another library as long as they support preserving comments, with toml
